# Moving an image with Tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I don't know what to do to get my object (picture) to move. This is what I have so far:

1st method in a class:

```
self.player1 = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="player1.png")
```

2nd method in a class:

```
# this puts this image in a square grid
self.player1_x = j*50
self.player1_y = i*50
self.canvas.create_image(self.player1_x, self.player1_y, anchor=NW, image=self.player1)
```

3rd method in a class (clicking on a specific button calls this method):

```
self.player1_x = self.player1_x
self.player1_y -= 50
self.canvas.move(self.player1, self.player1_x, self.player1_y)
```

When I write it like this, nothing happens and the image doesn't move. Can you help me with that? Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear, you didn't provide any real code (see how to create a [mcve]), your chances of getting an answer are very low.

Answer (score 0):

`self.player1` is currently not set to the image on the canvas but the image file itself. To get the behaviour you want you should do the following:

```
self.player1_image = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="player1.png")

# Create the player1 object
self.player1 = self.canvas.create_image(self.player1_x, self.player1_y, anchor=NW, image=self.player1_image)

# Move the player1 object. Move takes 3 arguments, the object to move and the x and y to move by, not the coordinates to move to.
self.canvas.move(self.player1, 0, -50)
```